# Cannot solve this circle theorem problem any hints?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

[image: Diagram here]
I need to find out the angle S, tried lots of stuff, still couldn't solve it. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$m\,\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{CD\,}=74^\circ$ because it is subtended by $\angle CBD$ which has a measure of $37^\circ$.  Since $\overline{BD}$ is a diameter, $m\,\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{BC\,}=106^\circ$.  Therefore, $m\angle BAC=53^\circ$.

Comment: How did you figure out <COD before (180 - <BOC)  if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Antonio I didn't.  $\angle OBC$ is an inscribed angle, so the measure of the arc it inscribes is double the measure of its angle.

Comment: Thanks for replying, the half central angle theorem has many variations that it's tough to find out the tricky ones.

Comment: @Antonio Yes, that's why I made the diagram with $\overline{OD}$ on it.  It can really help to clarify the situation when you add auxiliary lines like that.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: call the top corner of the triangle $A$ and add the segment $OA$. That way you get an isocsceles triangle and you know one of its angles. That way you can find all the angles of this triangle. Do you see what is the relation between these angles and $S$?

Comment: Yes I know the angle between OA it's 106 degrees after doing 180-(2*37) but what about the left side of the arrow? cannot figure that out

Comment: Yes, and an inscribed angle is half of the central angle which subtends the same arc on the circle. Well, that way you get $S$.

Comment: Thanks now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try running a radius to the point near the top of the circle. This gives you an isosceles triangle. Can you see where to go from there?